# git fatal error Path with a does not make sense

Tags: git, sourceforge

I have existing code on my computer, then I have registerd my account on sourceforge, starting a git project. Now I need to send my local project on sourceforge remote space. On sf there's the instruction page:

**First time using Git**

```
cd miorep-code
git init
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add origin ssh://****/p/miorep/code
git push origin master
```

**Existing Repository**

```
cd miorep-code
git remote add origin ssh://****/p/miorep/code
git push origin master
```

If I follow the first set of instructions, I have a

> "Fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense"

when I get `git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'`.

If I follow the second set of instruction I get:

> error: src refspec master does not match any. 
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://****/p/ravenna/code'

when I exec the last command.

What's the correct set of instructions in my case? Why I get that error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first set of instructions doesn't make sense:

```
cd miorep-code
git init
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'
```

There needs to be a `git add` between `git init` and `git commit`, because otherwise `git` doesn't know *what* you want to commit.  Your second error...

```
error: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://**/p/ravenna/code'
```

...means you haven't actually committed anything to your local repository yet, so there is no `master` branch to push.

What you want to do is:

```
cd miorep-code
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin master
```

You'll note that this is *almost* identical to your first set of instructions, except we've add a `git add .` which means "add everything in my current directory and below to my repository".

Comment: It's seemed that remote add was needed.

Comment: Your answer seems wrong. `git commit -a` is supposed to be the equivalent of `git add . && git commit`. That's what the `-a` does, no?.

Comment: No.  `git commit -a` will commit all pending changes to files that are *already part of the repository*.  `git add .` would add all files contained recursively in the current directory.  In other words, `git add .` followed by `git commit` will add new files to the repository while `git commit -a` will just commit changes to existing files.

Comment: That seems like a terrible reason to downvote an answer, especially since you weren't the one who asked the question.  You're welcome to ask a *new* question to get the answer you're looking for!

Answer (score 37):

The single-quote ' is the problem. Change it to double-quotes, like "initial commit". Use double-quotes in **Windows-cmd** instead of single-quote.

@AndrewC: read this before doing the downvote: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Skipping-the-Staging-Area

Comment: That won't work per the above comments, since nothing will be added to make a commit.

Comment: I ran into the same problem yesterday. Change to double-quotes had helped. All untracked files, which manually copied to the git project folder, will automatically added to staged and then committed. -a option is a compound of the 2 actions.

Comment: "every file that is already tracked"  - there are no tracked files immediately after git init, per the above comments

Comment: In windows, change single-quote to double-quote would help to solve "Fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense".

Comment: Awesome, solved my problem! What's the explanation behind this? Is it that cmd doesn't treat single quotes as quotation marks in the same way as it does double quotes?

Comment: This is the exact answer to the question in the title. Not sure about the content of the question. But I had the same error and I did commit with `don't` inside a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem may be lurking.  You are mixing the `-a` and `.`, in other words these 2 are acceptable, but never together:

ok:

```
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'
```

ok:

```
git commit -m 'Initial commit' .
```

bad:

```
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit' .
```