# Git on Mac: -a command isn't working

Tags: macos, git, version-control

I'm trying to commit all files in a directory, using the **git commit -a "added some change"** command.

I'm working on Mac OS X, Leopard.

After I submit the command, the Terminal responds with:

**fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.**

Could someone please tell me if there's anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914919/git-fatal-error-path-with-a-does-not-make-sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git one uses the -m option to add a message. -a means all thus commits all changed files

type in your terminal:

```
git add -a -m "Added some change"
```

For future problems see

```
git commit -h

(... omitted output)
-m, --message <message>
                      commit message
(... omitted output)
Commit contents options
-a, --all             commit all changed files
(... omitted output)
```

Answer (score 1):

try git commit -am "some message"