# How to Pass Multiple Commands to Git BASH

Tags: git, bash

New to Git.  Running it on windows.  When I run this command in a .sh file (from a BASH shell), it works:

*cd /c/SomeDir && git commit -a -m "commit comment"*

I want to do that with a variable comment, so I want to call:
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe
and pass the above command (2 commands chained) as the parameter (with a different comment each time).

It doesn't work; looking for ideas...

**Clarification:** I'm using a utility to run commands, but basically, this is all I want to call:
Executable:
*C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe*
Parameters (if test.sh has everything it needs but the comment):
*bash /c/somewhere/test.sh "my comment"*

Alternatively, the Parameters could simply be:
*cd /c/MyRepoDir && git commit -a -m "my comment"*

**Further:**  Even after creating a .sh script, calling bash, and running that script, I still get an error, "Paths with -a does not make sense."  Then, even after doing what's recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914919/git-fatal-error-path-with-a-does-not-make-sense) (same commands), I STILL get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

try putting $1 in to reference the first parameter

```
cd /c/SomeDir && git commit -a -m "$1"
```

so myScript.sh contains your line, then

```
bash myScript.sh "this is my commit message"
```

an alternative to this approach from using cd is pushd and popd

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd mygitdir
git commit -a -m "$1"
popd
```

Comment: "Paths with -a does not make sense."  Reverting the "$1" back to hard coded, still calling bash as you indicate works.  Separated the 2 commands each on their own line (seemed like it was doing something with the cd command); same result.

Comment: So don't pass them as a parameter put those commands in a shell script, either bash or bat, and pass your comment as a parameter.

Comment: Confused; sounds exactly like your original suggestion.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused too.  Perhaps you can better explain the problem?  Give some examples of what you have and output, and an example of the output you might like.    This gives the world a chance to recreate your problem.

Comment: as you get further down the git road, you may find it easier not to use blanket commits, there are all kinds of temp files, and other shrapnel that just tends to crop up.

Comment: Added clarification.  Hope that helps.

Comment: can you provide the output of it not working?  It looks like it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101914/discussion-between-dudenumber4-and-calvin-taylor).